# Stop a file from being checked into a repository?

Tags: github, github-actions, gitignore

Is it possible to stop a file from being checked in? If so, how would you do this in a GitHub Action or comparable technology?

Conceptual (but not actual) workflow

1. Developer attempts to check in a file
2. Check the text to make sure that the string "Owner: Acme" is present in a comment
3. If the text string is not present then don't let the file get checked in

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if you prevent a file to be merged in a branch, through pull-request.

That means the file can still be checked-in, but not in a protected branch, updated only through pull-request.

Then you can use the [GitHub Action `xalvarez/prevent-file-change-action`](https://github.com/xalvarez/prevent-file-change-action): you might need to fork that action in order to add a file *content* search for a given pattern, but the idea remains: block any merge of files which do not follow your policy.